# odd warning with Core Data in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, core-data, ios5

I get the following warning when I run my app in iOS5

```
CoreData: warning: Relationship properties should be @dynamic, not ivars (entity foo, class foo, property bar).  This will be an error in the future.
```

the property bar is being declared in the class as @dynamic. I would like to fix this before it becomes "an error in the future".

Comment: Post the code that produces the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using the Xcode to generate your MO subclasses. You will not see this error from the classes generated by the IDE.

Comment: You where right. What it was complaining about was that in the .h file I declared the variables in the class definition like I would any other class. In iOS5 as long as you create an @property in the .h file and declare it in the model file your fine. No need to to have anything like NSString* bar;